# How to get the hive table output or text file in hdfs on which hive table created to .CSV format.

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

So there is one condition with the cluster i'm working on. Nothing can be taken out of cluster to linux box.

Files on which hive table are built are in sequence file format or text format.

I need to change those files to CSV format with out outputting them to linux box  and also i can create table from existing table which can be STORED AS CSVfile if possible. (i'm not sure if i can do that).

I have tried lot things..but couldn't do it unless i output it to linux box. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another hive table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE hivetable_csv ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' as 
select * from hivetable;
```

Then copy the table contents to a new directory

```
hadoop fs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/csv_dump/* | hadoop fs -put - /user/username/hivetable.csv
```

Alternatively, you can also try

```
hadoop fs -cp
```